# How come 129, which is 8-bit number, is stored as -127 in signed char in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, char, overflow

I declared signed char and stored 129, an 8-bit number, in it. when typecasted it into integer and printed the result, its -127. I understand that it is overflow, but the confusion occurs when you look at the binary of 129 which is 10000001. In signed char, most significant bit is reserved as a sign bit and rest of the 7 bits are used to store the number's binary. According to this concept, 129 should be stored as -1. MSG representing negative sign and rest of the 7-bits are 0000001 which makes 1.
How come 129 becomes -127 when the binary of 129 makes -1.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a=129;
    cout<<(int) a; // OUTPUT IS -127
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're incorrect on what `10000001` is.  See the table on the right hand side of the page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Where did you get that idea about the representation of negative numbers? No modern machine uses it.

Comment: `float` and `double` use a sign-bit that way, but integers use two's complement (which is guaranteed in C++20).

Comment: @Eljay if signed CHAR does not uses most significant bit as a Sign-bit than why does 8-bit signed CHAR has a range of -128 to 127 ? Shouldn't it be 2^8 ?

Comment: @NathanOliver Brother I have seen this table and according to 2's compliment 10000001 is -127. If this is the case then it means in signed Char MSB is not used as sign-bit ? if not then then range of signed Char ought to be 2^8 rather than 2^7.

Comment: The MSB is the sign bit, it's just that negative numbers user the opposite bit pattern of positive numbers.  If they didn't, we wouldn't be able to represent all possible 256 possibilities.  Here is a great video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4

Comment: @NathanOliver Got it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your current idea of negative numbers is like this:

- 00000001 == 1
- 10000001 == -1
- 01111111 == 127
- 11111111 == -127

This means that you have only available range of integers -127...127 and
also you have two zeros. (00000000 == 0 and 10000000 == -0)

**Best method is so called two's complement**. For any number x, you negate binary representation and add 1 to get -x.
It means:

- 00000001 == 1
- 11111111 == -1
- 01111111 == 127
- 10000001 == -127
- 10000000 == -128

In this way only 00000000 is zero and you have the widest range -128...127.
Also CPU don't need additional instructions for adding signed numbers because it's identical to unsigned number addition and subtraction.

You may wonder, why to add 1. Without it, it's called one's complement.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement

Comment: I appreciate your effort to indite such a structured answer. Brother I do understand negative numbers are represented via 2's compliment and 10000001 represents -127. My confusion about this is that when number stored in Signed CHAR is less than 128, the most significant bit serves as determining sign of the number only....it serves as a sign-bit and rest of 7 bits determines the number, but when overflow occurs, all the 8 bits are used to represent the number and MSG starts serving as determining the number itself and not the sign. How the behaviour of memory changes dynamically?

Comment: By MSG you mean? Madison Square Garden? ;) Maybe MSB, most significant bit.

Comment: char is 8 bits. Interpretation of those bits come whether char is signed or unsigned. It doesn't change by itself.

Comment: I reckon you didn't comprehend my question...
I am talking about signed bit. You would be acquainted with this knowledge that in signed Char, 7 bits store binary of a number and the Most significant bit determines the sign, but when overflow occurs and 128 is stored in signed char, it displays -128 whose binary is 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. Now All the 8 bits are used to represent the whole number, how come the policy that only 7 bits will represent the number itself in signed Char has altered.

Comment: Whether or not the overflow happened, the most significant bit still represents the sign of char. For example: 10000001 is not -129, it is -127. And to be correct, overflow happens when you add one to -1. Because then 11111111 turns to 00000000.

Answer (score 0):

Every current computer stores low level signed integers in a format known as two's complement.

In two's complement, MAX_POSITIVE+1 is MIN_NEGATIVE.

```
0x00000000 is 0.
0x00....0V is V.
0x01....11 is MAX_POSITIVE
0x10....00 is MIN_NEGATIVE
0x11....11 is -1.
```

This looks weird at first glance.

But, it means that the logic of addition for positive and negative numbers is the same.  In fact, signed and unsigned math works out to be the same, except on overflow a positive signed number becomes a negative number, while the overflow of a positive unsigned number wraps around to 0.

Note that in C++, overflowing a signed number is undefined behavior, not because the hardware traps it, but because by making it UB the compiler is free to assume "adding positive numbers together is positive".  But at the machine code level, the implementation is 2s complement, and C++ has defined converting from signed to unsigned as following the 2s complement assumption.

Comment: You're off by one.  `0x01....1 is MAX_POSITIVE` and `0x10....00 is MIN_NEGATIVE`